# STM32 Complementary Pwm Dead Time

Tags: c, stm32

I am trying to create a complementary Pwm with variable frequency with Tim1 inverted and Tim1x non Inverted vice versa. But with the change in frequency my duty also changes and I can not figure out the exact reason of it, I am totally new with this MCU and to 32Bit MCU as well. It will be really appreciable if you could help me with your expert opinion. For your reference I am attaching my MXcube generated code as well as some picture which will give you an idea what i have done till now to meet my expectation with this code.

My TIM1 INIT.

```
    static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

      TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
      TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
      TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
      htim1.Instance = TIM1;
      htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
      htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_DOWN;
      htim1.Init.Period = 400;
      htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
      htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
      htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
      sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
      sConfigOC.Pulse = 180;
      sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
      sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
      sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
      sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
      sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
      if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_3;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 130;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
      sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
      HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

    }
```

This is the method to change the frequency.

```
    void pwmData(uint16_t dat){
    __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim1,dat);

    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1,dat*0.50);
    }
```

My main method.

```
    int main(void)
    {
      HAL_Init();

      SystemClock_Config();

      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_DMA_Init();
      MX_TIM1_Init();
      MX_ADC1_Init();
      MX_TIM2_Init();
      HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
      HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
      HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, uADCVal, 6);
      HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
      HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
      while (1)
      {
      if (flagu) {
        AD1 += uADCVal[0];
        AD2 += uADCVal[1];
        AD3 += uADCVal[2];
        AD4 += uADCVal[3];
        AD5 += uADCVal[4];
        AD6 += uADCVal[5];
        if (count >= 500) {
            uADC1 = AD1/500;
            AD1=0;
            uADC2 = AD2/500;
            volt = (float)uADC2*0.00080244078;
            AD2=0;
            uADC3 = AD3/500;
            temp2 =(float)uADC3*0.99;
            AD3=0;
            uADC4 = AD4/500;
            AD4=0;
            uADC5 = AD5/500;
            AD5=0;
            uADC6 = AD6/500;
            AD6=0;
            count=0;
        }
        flagu=0;
    }
      pwmData(uADC1);
      }
    }
```

My expectation is to get a complementary Pwm with variable frequency and fixed duty cycle and what i am getting is change in frequency affects my duty cycle too. My duty cycle is also changes when i try to change the frequency.

Comment: Why `temp2 =(float)uADC3*0.99;`?  `temp2` is never used.

Comment: It is related to another stuff and there is no connection with the PWM.

Comment: the duty cycle changes because the duty cycle reflects the ratio of PULSE / AAR. If you change the AAR, you have to adapt also the pulse withds. Example: AAR = 100 and Pulse = 25 -> that gives you a 25% duty cycle. If you change the AAR to 50 but keep the Pulse, then you get a 50% duty cycle with a doubled output frequency.